# Confidence limits for constrained penalized log likelihood model

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, regularization, constrained-regression

I am estimating parameter $\beta$ as:

\begin{align}
\hat \beta &=  \mathop{\mathrm{arg\,max}}_\beta \;\; l(\beta;X,y) - \frac{\lambda}{2}\left(\tilde y-g(\beta,\tilde X)\right)^\prime C^\prime C\left(\tilde y-g(\beta,\tilde X)\right)\\
&s.t.\\
& \;\;\;\;\; A\beta\leq 0\\
&where\\
& \tilde y = (y^\prime,y^{\ast\,\prime})^\prime\\
&\tilde X = (X^\prime,X^{\ast\,\prime})^\prime\\
& g(p,Q) = \exp(Qp)
\end{align}

How should I go about estimating the confidence limits on $\hat \beta$ theoretically?

Comment: $ l(\beta;X,y) = ?$

Comment: Most software would supply an in-buildt method for getting a standard error e.g. using the delta-method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap to estimate $\beta$ confidence intervals.
Otherwise, you'll need to derive the variance of $\beta$.